# Cache de arquivo remoto com atualizações por intervalo com PHP

Tags: php, cache

Estou desenvolvendo um portal de notícias e estou usando um [API de previsão do tempo](http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo). O problema é que toda vez que as pessoas abrem a página, o PHP baixa o [JSON do API](http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo/json/feira%20de%20santana-BA), e isso acaba interferindo na velocidade de carregamento da página.

Afim de resolver este problema e economizar largura de banda, eu pensei em fazer um cache desse JSON e baixar atualizações em um intervalo de 15 minutos, mas não tenho ideia por onde começar.

Vocês podem me ajudar? Desde já grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é utilizar um sistema de caches como o [memcached](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.memcached.php).
No seu código em que pega o JSON você faz um check condicional que vê se este JSON já está armazenado no cache, caso esteja você simplesmente pega ele de lá (o que é uma operação instântanea já que geralmente o cache vai armazenar em RAM), caso o JSON não esteja presente você pega ele do servidor externo e armazena no cache. Em código vai ser algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$memcached = new Memcached('pool');

$data = $memcached->get('alguma_previsao');
if ($data === Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND) { // dados não estão no cache
    $data = getJSONdoServidorExterno(); // aqui você pega o JSON como já faz normalmente

    $memcached->add('alguma_previsao', $data, 60 * 15); // armazena o JSON por 15 minutos no cache (60 segundos * 15)
}
$jsonFinal = $data; // aqui você tem o JSON de que precisa
```